# Rewrite rule to re-write old to pretty URLs

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I want `https://www.example.com/somePage.php?id=1234` to be redirected to `https://www.example.com/tool/1234` (so that legacy links and bookmarks work).

I think I am close, but this appears to not work...

```
RewriteRule ^somePage.php?toolid=([0-9]+)$ /tool/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: `.htaccess` or directly in your server config?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod\_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Answer (score 1):

You can't match the query string in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. You need to use a `RewriteCond` directive and compare against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

But also, assuming you have an internal rewrite later in your config file that rewrites back to the (real) ugly URL then you can't do a simple redirect, as it will result in a redirect loop. You need to make sure you only redirect the initial request, not the rewritten URL.

Assuming this is `.htaccess`, based on your existing `RewriteRule` *pattern*, try the following, near the top of your config file:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^toolid=(/d+)$
RewriteRule ^somePage\.php$ /tool/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Note, however, that your example URLs differ from your code example. I've gone with your code example.

The `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is empty on the initial request, but gets set to "200" after a successful internal rewrite. So, this avoids a redirect loop in per-directory `.htaccess` files.

Make sure you've cleared your browser cache, since any erroneous 301s (whilst testing) will have been cached by the browser.

Comment: This is very helpful, but it does not appear to be working. I know the .htaccess file is working because this application uses a front controller and is then parsed internally (so we don't need re-write, we use routes in PHP and regular expressions).  What's my next step to debug this?

Comment: The above should match the example URL given, except for the "toolid" vs "id" parameter. The order of directives is important, the above redirect will need to go _before_ your existing rewrites. If you add your complete `.htaccess` file to the question we can have a better look.

Comment: And when you say "does not appear to be working" - what actually happens? Nothing at all? Error?

Comment: "nothing" happens. There is a re-write directive below it that re-writes everything to index.php (front controller). That fires normally. It's like it is skipping over this because of a non-match.

Comment: The above should redirect a URL of the form `/somePage.php?toolid=1234` (exact match, case-sensitive). Try temporarily removing the first `RewriteCond` directive that checks against `REDIRECT_STATUS`.

Comment: Did anything happen after removing the first _condition_? If you got too many redirects then we need to see why `REDIRECT_STATUS` wasn't working (we can use an alternative and check against `THE_REQUEST`). If still nothing happened then either there is a conflict with existing directives (please include your complete `.htaccess` file in your question) or the _regex pattern_ is simply not matching, in which case you need to confirm the _exact_ URL and pattern you are using.